# Local npm dependency "does not a contain a package.json file" in docker build, but runs fine with npm start

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, dependencies, dockerfile

I have an npm module I'm working on locally that is a dependency in a client app.

Directory structure is basically the following:

```
/app
  /client
    /src
      App.js
    package.json
    Dockerfile.dev
  /shared
    /contexts
      package.json
      test.js
    /hooks
```

My `package.json` is the following:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "contexts": "file:../shared/contexts",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Importing with the following into `client/src/App.js`:

```
import { testImport } from 'contexts/test';
```

Works as expected when I run `npm start`.

The issue I'm running into is with running:

```
docker build -t sockpuppet/testapp -f Dockerfile.dev .
```

It fails and I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "../shared/contexts" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Here is he Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

How should I be handling local npm dependencies?

Also, adding something like the following to `COPY` the `/shared` into the image generates a `COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../shared/contexts ()` error:

```
COPY ../shared ./
```

Comment: where you place the Dockerfile in hierarchy?

Comment: can you show your dockerfile, seems like the context issue

Comment: `"../shared/contexts"` this out of the context of Dockerfile, you are not copying in the Dockerfile then how you got this error

Comment: Anyway to get around this? Only thing I can think is to not make it a local npm dependency, but then I'd lose the benefit of doing so. `COPY ../shared ./` does generate the `outside build context` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this works. I changed my `Dockerfile.dev` to the following:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./shared /shared
COPY ./web /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

From the base project directory (where `/shared` and `/web` reside), I run:

```
docker build -t sockpuppet/client -f ./web/Dockerfile.dev .
```

Comment: I don't see .web, where did it come from?